# How to call up a ger who converted with his father?

Tags: names, torah-service, conversion-to-judaism, family-members

In general a Ger is called up as [name] Ben Avraham. However, what if the Ger converted as a child together with his parents? I would think it is the same but I recently saw someone who is in that situation who was called up Ben [his father's hebrew name]. Is there a source for either way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Gemara in Yevamos 101:](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9759&st=&pgnum=212) mentions that Rav Shmuel the son of Yehuda reports about himself: ואנא גר אנא (“I am a convert”), yet he is named בר יהודה (son of Yehuda), Rashi explains, that this is since his natural father converted together with him.

Comment: What about if the person already had a Jewish Father (his Mother was not Jewish) and he converted. Could he be called then by his Father's name?

Comment: @Yehoshua - Please feel free to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) your question.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I think this a continuation of this question.